# Embedded entities in Objectify don't appear to auto-generate an Id

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm using Objectify with my first serious Google App Engine project, and generally it's all going swimmingly (what a lovely library!). Unfortunately, I've come across a problem when persisting my entities.

My basic structure is as follows:

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    @Id
    long id = 123;
    @Embedded
    Child[] children;
}

@Entity
class Child {
    @Id
    Long id;
}
```

I am manually declaring the ids of the parent entities, but I want the embedded child entities to automatically generate an id. I did wonder about just removing the @Id in the child entity entirely and coding around it, but then I get errors about entities needing the @Id.

Can someone please help? I am using the id, in order to compare changes between parent entities' children, so it's fairly fundamental to the current way I've designed it. I can re-architect though, if that would be a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Entity_Representation , it doesn't look like @Embedded entities are actually separate entities in your datastore at all.  They're just stored as properties directly in fields of the parent object.

If you want the Child entities to be their own, separately-accessible objects, you should change `Parent` to hold an array of Keys or IDs, and then instantiate your `Child` objects separately.  That'll generate ids for each Child (which you can store in the id array in the `Parent`).

Comment: Ok, thank you. That sounds very sensible, although I'm afraid some of the concepts are still a little too new to me to precisely understand every bit at the moment. I shall re-architect accordingly, and try re-reading that link a few more times ;)